# Why ?.let can prevent nullPointException in multithreading?

Tags: kotlin

As we know, the value of a global variable can be modified by other threads at any time. However why can `?.let` in kotlin prevent an NPE in multithreading? For example:

```
   var demo : Demo? = null
    demo = Demo()
    Thread{
        demo?.let {
            while (true){
                it.run()
                Thread.sleep(300)
            }
        }
    }.start()
    Thread.sleep(3000)
    demo = null
```

In the above programme, the child thread can be executed normally, though the main thread has set the variable `demo` to null.

So, why can't the 'it' in the construction of 'let' be influenced by other thread? Is it a deep copy of the Object 'demo'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, why the 'it' in the construction of 'let' can not be influenced by other thread?

`.let { }` has really nothing magical. It's a very simple function. When you write `demo?.let { println(it) }`, the code is effectively equivalent to:

```kotlin
val it = demo
if (it != null) {
    println(it)
}
```

So as you can see, a new variable is created and set to the value of `demo`. Therefore, if other threads modify `demo`, `it` is not affected.

> It's a deep copy of the Object 'demo'?

It's really *not* a deep copy: if a thread mutates the properties of the `Demo` instance, they will be visible by any code that accesses that instance*, even through the `it` variable.

However, you don't need a deep copy for this code to work fine. `demo` is a reference variable that initially points to the `Demo()` instance created at the beginning of the code.

When we do `val it = demo` (from the code equivalent to `?.let`), we copy the current value of the `demo` variable into `it`, and that value is the *reference* to the `Demo` instance. We say that `it` "points to" the same `Demo` instance as `demo`.

When the other thread sets `demo` to `null`, it doesn't change anything in the `Demo` instance. This has the effect that, now, `demo` doesn't point anymore to the initial `Demo` instance. But `it` still points to it.

(*although there are some subtleties here, like happen-before relationships, volatile variables etc., but let's not complicate things)

Answer (score 4):

Another supplementary point to help with your understanding.

There is no concept of a class instance becoming null. If you are working with an instance, it exists and it is not null.

**References** can become null. You can have multiple references to the same instance. As long as there exists somewhere at least one reference to a class instance, that class instance still exists, even if some of the references that used to point to it are now pointing at something else, such as `null`.

If you do this, you are not copying your class instance, and definitely not deep-copying it! You are only copying the **reference**.

```
val item = demo
```

If `demo` is changed to point at `null`, that has no effect on the instance of Demo itself, and `item` is still pointing at that same, unchanged instance.

Since `.let` internally copies a reference in the same way, it is preserving that reference even if the `demo` property is changed to point at something else or `null`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a deep copy. It's literally the object that it was before. What you need to realize is that variables are just pointers to objects. Say you have

```
var demo : Demo? = Demo()
var demo2 : Demo? = demo
var demo3 : Demo? = demo
var demo4 : Demo? = demo
```

you have 4 variables pointing to the same object. If you do

```
demo = null
```

after these 4 lines then you merely make that variable no longer point to that object. `demo2`, `demo3` and `demo4` still will point to the object that you assigned to `demo` in the beginning. The same happens in the `let` block where `it` is just another variable that was assigned the same object in the beginning of the block so that any assignments to the original `demo` won't have effect on `it`